# How do I load my object using hibernate when there is double @id in my entity bean?

Tags: hibernate

```
@Id
int master_id;

@Id
int id;
```

...this is not working:

```
User user= (User) session.load(User.class, new Integer(master_id), new Integer(id));
```

---

```
load(Class theClass, Serializable id)
```

I replaced the last two arguments with a serializable object and still cannot retrive the object.

Answer (score 2):

Well, problem solved using `@Embeddable`!

```
@Embeddable
public class UsertId implements Serializable{
    int master_id;
    int id;
    //.....setter &getter
}

//and in the bean, the type for Id should be UsertId
@Id
UsertId id;
```